# how to setup a maven spring-mvc hibernate mysql project in netbeans

Tags: mysql, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, netbeans

I can't setup a maven project in my netbeans ide i'm getting a [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

error... Help

Comment: You need to provide more details!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, "__write/debug-my-code__", "__recommend/search-something-for-me__", "__tutorial__" requests and "__low-effort__", "__unclear__", "__opinion-based__" questions are [Off-Topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Good questions instead, as described in [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), have **research effort**, a **clear explanation of the problem** and should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be useful to future visitors.